# Diagonal submatrices of the inverse of a $p \times p$ block matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite, block-matrices

Let $X$ be a square, symmetric, positive definite matrix that can be decomposed into $p\times p$ block matrices:

$$X = \begin{bmatrix} X_{11} & X_{12} & \ldots & X_{1p}\\
X_{21} & X_{22} & \ldots & X_{2p}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
X_{p1} & X_{p2} & \ldots & X_{pp}
\end{bmatrix}$$

Let $Y$ denote the inverse of $X$ that consists of $p \times p$ submatrices:

$$Y = X^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix} Y_{11} & Y_{12} & \ldots & Y_{1p}\\
Y_{21} & Y_{22} & \ldots & Y_{2p}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
Y_{p1} & Y_{p2} & \ldots & Y_{pp}
\end{bmatrix}$$

**I would like to write the diagonal submatrices $Y_{ii}$ for $1 \leq i \leq p$ as a function of the submatrices in $X$.**

**$\bf{p =2}$ case:** Since $X_{11}, X_{22}$ are positive definite (and invertible), then

$$Y = \begin{bmatrix} (X_{11} - X_{12}X_{22}^{-1}X_{21})^{-1} & -(X_{11}-X_{12}X_{22}^{-1} X_{21})^{-1}X_{12}X_{22}^{-1} \\
-(X_{22} - X_{21} X_{11}^{-1} X_{12})^{-1} X_{21}X_{11}^{-1} & (X_{22}-X_{21} X_{11}^{-1} X_{12})^{-1} \end{bmatrix}$$

so

1. $Y_{11} = (X_{11} - X_{12}X_{22}^{-1}X_{21})^{-1}$
2. $Y_{22} = (X_{22}-X_{21} X_{11}^{-1} X_{12})^{-1}$

**$\bf{p =3}$ case:** Since $X_{11}, X_{22}, X_{33}$ are positive definite (and invertible), then (if my math is right) we have the following

1. $Y_{11} = ((X_{11} - X_{13}X^{-1}_{11}X_{31}) - (X_{12}-X_{13}X^{-1}_{33}X_{32})(X_{22}-X_{23}X^{-1}_{33}X_{32})^{-1}(X_{21}-X_{23}X^{-1}_{33}X_{31}))^{-1}$
2. $Y_{22} = ((X_{22} - X_{21}X^{-1}_{11}X_{12}) - (X_{23}-X_{21}X^{-1}_{11}X_{13})(X_{33}-X_{31}X^{-1}_{11}X_{13})^{-1}(X_{32} - X_{31}X^{-1}_{11}X_{12}))^{-1}$
3. $Y_{33} = ((X_{33}-X_{31}X^{-1}_{11}X_{13}) - (X_{32}-X_{31}X^{-1}_{11}X_{12})(X_{22}-X_{21}X^{-1}_{11}X_{12})^{-1}(X_{23}-X_{21}X^{-1}_{11}X_{13}))^{-1}$

For the general $p \times p$ case, is it possible to write $$Y_{ii} = (Z_{ii})^{-1}$$
where $Z_{ii}$ can be written as a function of the submatrices in $X$? Would $Z_{ii}$ be a Schur complement of some sort?

Comment: Just with scalars (like block $1\times1$ matrices) this is not trivial to write. Try to write the inverse of the diagonal of a $3\times3$ matrix as an exercise for example. The case $2\times2$ is much more tractable.

Comment: Maybe the required representation for $Y_{ij}$ can be found by the induction on $p$ as follows.
First represent $X$ as a $2\times 2$ block matrix
$X = \begin{bmatrix} X'_{11} & X'_{12} \\
X'_{21} & X_{pp}
\end{bmatrix}$, next represent the $2\times 2$ block matrix
$Y=X^{-1}$ with the formula for $p=2$ case, then plug into it the already found representations for the blocks $Y'_{ij}$ of the $(p-1)\times (p-1)$ block matrix $Y'=X_{11}^{'-1}$.

Comment: Use gaussian elimination symbolically and _a lot of time and paper_ to get there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting a direct expression isn't going to happen, because it is like asking for a direct expression for the components $L_{ij}$ and $U_{ij}$ of an *LU* decomposition given any general matrix $A$.

But you can get a symbolic result by using $p$ recursions, each time reducing the size of the matrix to be inverted by one order.

I will proceed with the concrete example of a $p=4$ matrix that will illustrate the process to make it into a $p=3$ matrix.

1. First split the given matrix ${\rm X}_{44}$ into 4 partitions

   $${\rm X}_{44}=\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
   X_{11} & X_{12} & X_{13} & X_{14}\\
   X_{21} & X_{22} & X_{23} & X_{24}\\
   X_{31} & X_{32} & X_{33} & X_{34}\\
   \hline X_{41} & X_{42} & X_{43} & X_{44}
   \end{array}\right]=\begin{bmatrix}{\rm X}_{33} & {\rm X}_{34}\\
   {\rm X}_{43} & X_{44}
   \end{bmatrix}$$

   A bit of nomenclature here, the italicized letter $X_{44}$ designates the sub-matrix as given, and the upright letters ${\rm X}_{33}$, ${\rm X}_{34}$, and ${\rm X}_{43}$ designate the block matrices that contain multiple sub-matrices. Each subscript $3$ on upright letters above actually represents a range $1 \ldots 3$ for the sub-matrices included.

   More specifically, the above notation represents the following block matrices

   $$\begin{aligned}{\rm X}_{33} & =\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
   X_{11} & X_{12} & X_{13}\\
   X_{21} & X_{22} & X_{23}\\
   X_{31} & X_{32} & X_{33}
   \end{array}\right]\\
   {\rm X}_{34} & =\left[\begin{array}{c}
   X_{14}\\
   X_{24}\\
   X_{34}
   \end{array}\right]\\
   {\rm X}_{43} & =\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
   X_{41} & X_{42} & X_{43}\end{array}\right]
   \end{aligned}$$
2. Do the same for the inverse ${\rm Y}_{44}$

   $${\rm Y}_{44}=\left[\begin{array}{ccc|c}
   Y_{11} & Y_{12} & Y_{13} & Y_{14}\\
   Y_{21} & Y_{22} & Y_{23} & Y_{24}\\
   Y_{31} & Y_{32} & Y_{33} & Y_{34}\\
   \hline Y_{41} & Y_{42} & Y_{43} & Y_{44}
   \end{array}\right]=\begin{bmatrix}{\rm Y}_{33} & {\rm Y}_{34}\\
   {\rm Y}_{43} & Y_{44}
   \end{bmatrix}$$
3. Solve the matrix inversion problem for the components of ${\rm Y}_{44}$

   $$\begin{bmatrix}{\rm Y}_{33} & {\rm Y}_{34}\\
   {\rm Y}_{43} & Y_{44}
   \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}{\rm X}_{33} & {\rm X}_{34}\\
   {\rm X}_{43} & X_{44}
   \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1_{\{3,3\}} & 0_{\{3,1\}}\\
   0_{\{1,3\}} & 1_{\{1,1\}}
   \end{bmatrix}$$

   by splitting it up into four equations (one for each block in the partition) to get the result

   $$\small \begin{aligned}{\rm Y}_{33}=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
   Y_{11} & Y_{12} & Y_{13}\\
   Y_{21} & Y_{22} & Y_{23}\\
   Y_{31} & Y_{32} & Y_{33}
   \end{array}\right] & =\left(\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
   X_{11} & X_{12} & X_{13}\\
   X_{21} & X_{22} & X_{23}\\
   X_{31} & X_{32} & X_{33}
   \end{array}\right]-\left[\begin{array}{c}
   X_{14}\\
   X_{24}\\
   X_{34}
   \end{array}\right]X_{44}^{-1}\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
   X_{41} & X_{42} & X_{43}\end{array}\right]\right)^{-1}\\
   {\rm Y}_{34}=\left[\begin{array}{c}
   Y_{14}\\
   Y_{24}\\
   Y_{34}
   \end{array}\right] & =-{\rm Y}_{33}\left[\begin{array}{c}
   X_{14}\\
   X_{24}\\
   X_{34}
   \end{array}\right]X_{44}^{-1}\\
   Y_{44} & =\left(X_{44}-\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
   X_{41} & X_{42} & X_{43}\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
   X_{11} & X_{12} & X_{13}\\
   X_{21} & X_{22} & X_{23}\\
   X_{31} & X_{32} & X_{33}
   \end{array}\right]^{-1}\left[\begin{array}{c}
   X_{14}\\
   X_{24}\\
   X_{34}
   \end{array}\right]\right)^{-1}\\
   {\rm Y}_{43}=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
   Y_{41} & Y_{42} & Y_{43}\end{array}\right] & =-Y_{44}\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
   X_{41} & X_{42} & X_{43}\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
   X_{11} & X_{12} & X_{13}\\
   X_{21} & X_{22} & X_{23}\\
   X_{31} & X_{32} & X_{33}
   \end{array}\right]^{-1}
   \end{aligned}$$
4. Assemble ${\rm Y}_{44}$ from the four block matrices ${\rm Y}_{33}$, ${\rm Y}_{34}$, ${\rm Y}_{43}$ and $Y_{44}$ calculated above.

   Note that to complete this step, you need to compute 3 block matrix inverses

   | Required Inverses for $p=4$ |
   | --- |
   | $$X_{44}^{-1}$$ |
   | $$\left[\begin{array}{ccc} X_{11} & X_{12} & X_{13}\\ X_{21} & X_{22} & X_{23}\\ X_{31} & X_{32} & X_{33} \end{array}\right]^{-1}$$ |
   | $$\left(\left[\begin{array}{ccc} X_{11} & X_{12} & X_{13}\\ X_{21} & X_{22} & X_{23}\\ X_{31} & X_{32} & X_{33} \end{array}\right]-\left[\begin{array}{c} X_{14}\\ X_{24}\\ X_{34} \end{array}\right]X_{44}^{-1}\left[\begin{array}{ccc} X_{41} & X_{42} & X_{43}\end{array}\right]\right)^{-1}$$ |
   | $$\left(X_{44}-\left[\begin{array}{ccc} X_{41} & X_{42} & X_{43}\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{ccc} X_{11} & X_{12} & X_{13}\\ X_{21} & X_{22} & X_{23}\\ X_{31} & X_{32} & X_{33} \end{array}\right]^{-1}\left[\begin{array}{c} X_{14}\\ X_{24}\\ X_{34} \end{array}\right]\right)^{-1}$$ |

   So at this point, you would apply this method recursively to the 3 inversed above to get 3×3=9 inverses of $p=2$ order. And so on, until you get down to the component inverses $X_{ij}^{-1}$

   You can summarize the number of inverses required for each size $p$ as follows

   | Block matrix size $p$ | Number of sub-matrix $X_{ij}$ inverses |
   | --- | --- |
   | $1$ | $1$ |
   | $2$ | $4$ |
   | $3$ | $11$ |
   | $4$ | $30$ |
   | .. | .. |
   | $p$ | $3^{(p-1)}+(p-1)$ |

PS. Be mindful of the designation of a block matrix ${\rm X}_{ij}$ vs. a component sub-matrix $X_{ij}$ as they are of different sizes.